# Выберите вариант, соответствующий современным нормам грамматики

Tags: грамотная-речь

1. (Следователю стало все ясно – следователь все понял), прочитав инструкцию.
2. (По приезде – по приезду) с учебы оформляется отчет о проделанной на курсах работе.
3. Встречаясь с затруднениями, (у моего подзащитного не хватило выдержки для их решения – мой подзащитный не мог их решить из-за невыдержанности).
4. (При входе и сходе с эскалатора – при входе на эскалатор и выходе с него) будьте осторожны.
5. Игнатьева А.В. на протяжении  длительного периода  (систематически занималась подделкой с корыстной целью различных документов - систематически занималась подделкой различных документов с корыстной целью).

Comment: @sana159, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

А что неясно? Всё просто: основное и добавочное действия должен выполнять один деятель, а фраза должна звучать по-русски.

1. Следователю стало все ясно-безличное предложение, деятеля нет, не подходит. Надо: Следователь все понял, прочитав инструкцию.
2. По приезде (после приезда) с учебы оформляется отчет о проделанной на курсах работе.
3. Встречаясь с затруднениями,  мой подзащитный не мог их решить из-за невыдержанности).
4. При входе на эскалатор и выходе с него будьте осторожны.
5. Игнатьева А.В. на протяжении длительного периода  систематически занималась подделкой различных документов с корыстной целью.